ROS1: RobotModel errors in RViz
Using ROS1, when I run the launch file below, the map is loaded successfully in Rviz, the robot is shown with white color. However, there are errors shown in RViz related to RobotModel: URDF is stated to be parsed OK; however, the other parameters like base_link, i get error messages: no transform from [base_link] to map. In the global status, there is the following error: Fixed Frame: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist...how can i solve this problem? I am using simulation and I did not launch gazebo before executing the below launch file. The below gives the list of topics opened when running the launch file
rostopic list 
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/clicked_point
/initialpose 
/joint_states
/map
/map_metadata
/move_base_simple/goal
/particlecloud
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/tf_static



<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="map_file" default="/home/maps/map.yaml"/>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>


  <!-- Map server -->
  <node pkg="map_server" name="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="$(arg move_forward_only)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- rviz -->
  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_navigation)/rviz/turtlebot3_navigation.rviz"/>
  </group>
</launch>

